# Sharing files between centOS on virtualbox and windows 7 as the host

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I have centOS 5.5 installed on virtual box it has no GUI so every thing is command based. I want to make a folder in centOS which i can share with my windows 7 host OS such that i can send files to and fro seamlessly. I am new to linux and i managed to install samba. I looked up some tips on net but i ended up getting confused and none of them worked. Can someone explain to me how i can do this in a straight forward way from how i can configure samba to how i can mount the folder such that it can be seen on the host operating system. I am completely lost.please help.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox's [shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) feature will enable you to easily share folders between the host and client without having to install extra software on either one (other than the VBox Guest Additions).

Answer (score 1):

First, install samba using yum:

```
yum install samba
```

Then specify the samba password for your user:

```
smbpasswd user_name
```

Now you have to configure samba:

```
vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Go to the end of the file and write this:

```
[shared_folder]
   valid users = your_user
   public = no
   path = /your/path/to/share
   printable = no
   writable = yes
```

Save the file, and restart Samba:

```
restart samba   or   /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

Now you can go to Windows and create a shortcut to `\\ip\shared_folder`

Comment: When i try to set the password i get "Failed to find entry for user" what's going on. Also clarify on what you mean by ip in \\ip\shared_folder. Is it an ip address

Comment: if you are using a Linux user called "mike", then you do `smbpasswd` mike and then in the conf file you write `valid users = mike`.

Comment: If you centOS machine has the ip 192.168.1.100 then, from Windows you have to create a shortcut to `\\192.168.1.100\shared_folder`

Comment: How do you check the ip address for the virtual machine.

Comment: In Linux you can use `ifconfig` con Command line fot viewing ip information. Anyway you have to be sure that your Virtual Machine is getting ip maybe with Bridge connection, go to the Virtual Machine Network configuration in Virtual Box configuration.

Comment: You need not use Samba in this situation; if you only need to share folders between the host OS and the guest, VirtualBox's native shared folders implementation will easily suffice. Review [this howto](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) for further details on how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a "Failed to find entry for user" you can add users via `smbpasswd -a <username>`.